# Javascript charCodeAt() not returning correct codes.. or is it?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to find the keycodes (if that's even what I need) and to change the character to the incremented keycode (this is just for a coding challenge) and it's not working

```
function LetterChanges(str) { 
var newString = "";
var keyCode;
  for(var i = 0; i < str.length; ++i)
  {

    keyCode = str.charCodeAt(i);
    console.log(keyCode);
    if( keyCode > 57 && keyCode < 122)
    {

         //add 1 to the keycode

         newString += String.fromCharCode(i+1);
         //console.log(String.fromCharCode(i+1));

    }
    else if(keyCode === 90)
    {
        //if it's a z being examined, add an a
         newString += "a";
    }
    else
        //it is a symbol, so just add it to the new string without change
        newString += str[i];
    }
  return newString.toUpperCase();

}

console.log(LetterChanges("Charlie"));
```

Comment: I don't get it. What is the problem, exactly?

Comment: how did you arrive at `add 1 to the keycode` === (i+1) ? What is expected output? You have one `else` that can never be entered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Jsfiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/techsin/pnbuae83/1/

```
function codeIncreaser(input) {
    var str='', code=null;
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(input, function (e) {
        code = e.charCodeAt();
        if ((code>64 && code<90) || (code>96 && code<122)) {
            code++;
        } else if (code == 90) {
            code = 65;
        } else if (code == 122) {
            code = 97;
        }
        str += String.fromCharCode(code);
    });
    return str;
}

var text =  codeIncreaser('abczABC');
console.log(text);
```

This accommodates lowercase letters as well.

and if you wanna make code somewhat compact you could do something like this...

```
function $(i) {
    var s='', c;
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(i, function (e) {
        c = e.charCodeAt();
        ((c>64&&c<90)||(c>96&&c<122))?c++:((c == 90)?c=65:(c==122&&(c=97)));
        s += String.fromCharCode(c);
    });
    return s;
}

console.log($('abczABC @-@'));
```

Comment: Can you tell me why I'm getting the wrong codes I think http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=xsaULs3nSt ... shouldnt I be getting 68 for this one? I'm using http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes

Comment: You mean you want to know what is wrong in your code?

Comment: check this out for fun http://jsfiddle.net/techsin/ZvRnZ/13/ and the way i write code results in not even me being able to understand it.

Answer (score 2):

change

```
newString += String.fromCharCode(i+1);
```

to

```
newString += String.fromCharCode(keyCode+1);
```

Comment: Its output is `DIBSMJF`...advancing each letter of the input